# What's the German term for friends that you know from your childhood?

Tags: vocabulary

I once read a nice term that's used to describe friends that you've known ever since you were very little. It was something like "Sandbeckenkamaraden", but not exactly. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: The most common term for a childhood friend is actually _Schulfreund_, though that is apparently not what you're looking for.

Comment: You can actually say ''school friend'' in English, although it's probably more common ''old school friend'' for clarity.

Comment: and then there is also "Jugendfreund" which means friend of (so.) youth...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The word you are looking for is [Sandkastenfreund](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sandkastenfreund).

Comment: I know _Sandkastenliebe_ for married couples in sentences like _Er hat seine Sandkastenliebe geheiratet._

Comment: We've got something like *Sandkastenfreund* and all that English speakers have in mind when they talk about uniquely useful German words is *Schadenfreude*, it's a shame really :(

Comment: Schadenfreude ist die ehrlichste Freude. The word shows a degree of self awareness that is not universal.

Comment: Other related terms would be _Kindergartenfreund_ and _Schulfreund_, depending on the age at which you've met.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel; There are a lot of native German expressions in common use in English which fit better than English equivalents: Kindergarten, Doppelganger, Wunderkind, Wanderlust (that one is a beauty). Zeitgeist (overused but precise). Ersatz (although it has a connotation of something inferior in English). You sometimes hear Dummkopf instead of "blockhead", Zugzwang in chess - difficult to find another word that is equally concise.

Comment: Never heard that word, it might not be universally known.

Comment: @JohnD Kindergarten when used in American English does not have the same meaning it has in German.

Comment: @John D Doppelgänger has an umlaut by the way, I'm sure you knew that though.  Ansatz is very regularly used in mathematical English.  I don't think Zugzwang is very widely used in English as far as I know.

Comment: C.S. Lewis (who also knew something of English) liked  *sehnsucht* which in his context basically meant a deep longing, so deep it was hard to describe, almost a longing for a longing -- if interested, please see "Surprised by Joy" etc.

Comment: Ansatz - educated guess. I hadn't heard that one, thanks. I suspect Doppelgaenger got the usual ruthless simplification - what's that extra "e" doing there? Get rid of it !

Comment: Is it always the case in German that a vowel v with an umlaut can be converted to "ve" without the umlaut? I watch a lot of German/Scandinavian films and occasionally there is a sentence which needs no translation - it still makes sense in English after 1300 years of separation -- that's cool. True, zugzwang is restricted to chess. but every chess player knows what it means.

Comment: I'm fascinated by the similarities between English and German. There was a shift from "d" to "t" in German after the invasions of Britain eg mittel/middle, tuer/door, but they are still close enough for government work. Brueder/brother seems to be against the trend.